# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this WordPress error on a site I am building locally.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

I tried to allocate 1702064827 bytes in C:\xampp\htdocs\zerotozenithmedia\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5231.

Comment: Please add the code from your functions.php file at line 5231 to this post. Without viewing the code nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: If your functions.php file has more than 5000 lines you're doing something very, very wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Increase PHP Memory Limit in WordPress. Add This Code In `wpconfig.php` and your problem will be solved or you can increase the memory limit using the `php.ini`.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```